# Test to see if you are in a specific content block in TinyMCE and not allow a plugin to add to that content block if in it

Tags: plugins, tinymce

So I have a TinyMCE form on my page and it is pre-filled with "sections" (divs with specific class names).

I have a couple of plugins that will add to TinyMCE with more "sections".

I need it so when I push the plugin button it will test to make sure the cursor is not inside a "section" and paste a "section" inside another "section".

Not sure the direction I need to take to accomplish this.  Any help would be great.

**more info:**
So below is an example of a plugin that adds a button that just inserts a simple dov into the editor at the selection/cursor.

```
ed.addButton('pluginbutton', {
    title : 'MyPlugin',
    image : 'img/test.png',
    onclick : function() {
        ed.selection.setContent('<div>test</div>');
    }
});
```

I am currently thinking that [onBeforeSetContent](http://wiki.moxiecode.com/index.php/TinyMCE:API/tinymce.Editor/onBeforeSetContent) is the API event handler I need to set to process whether or not I am in another section and if so send a message to the screen.  If not just do the setContent method.  I am not sure exactly how to set that up though so I am still figuring that out.  Any help here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since it seems like you have control over the plugin, here is how I would edit it to work.

*Note:* I am using the jQuery method `closest`. I figured since you are on the jQuery core team, you are probably using it for this project. If not, just refactor that line as needed. The important part is that [`selection.getNode()`](http://wiki.moxiecode.com/index.php/TinyMCE:API/tinymce.dom.Selection/getNode) returns the DOM element that is the parent of both the start and end selection points.:

```
ed.addButton('pluginbutton', {
    title : 'MyPlugin',
    image : 'img/test.png',
    onclick : function() {
        if( !$(ed.selection.getNode()).closest('div.section').length ){
            ed.selection.setContent('<div class="section">test</div>'); 
        }
    }
});
```

**Additional thoughts**

Also, to make your plugin aware enough so it won't put a `div` as the child of a `p` tag, you could do something like this:

*Replace onclick above with this:*

```
onclick: function(){
    var $node = $(ed.selection.getNode());
    if( !$node.closest('div.section').length ){
       // Get highest element that is a direct child of the `body` tag:
       var $parent = $node.closest('body > *');
       // Wrap with our special section div
       if($parent.length) $parent.wrap('<div class="section"></div>');
    }
}
```

Comment: Sneaky JQuery implementation! Nice. And another case for that co-authoring function.

Comment: @Pekka Totally... we really need to suggest that. Maybe I'll type it up this week.

Comment: HA I already had something like you had in the first example.

Comment: that second example is useful as well...Thanks.

Comment: @RedWolves great! Good luck on your project!

Comment: I was using parents instead of closest but I like this approach better.

Comment: Fantastically simple.  Thanks so much

Answer (score 1):

I don't know TinyMCE specifically, but it should be possible to extract the current DOM element from `ed.selection`. If that is possible (I'm sure it is using some sort of getter function or property), you should be able to do the following:

- Mark a "forbidden" area using an id or class ("`<div class='protected'>` ")
- traverse through the selection's ancestry (using the `parentNode` property of the element) and check whether one of the parent elements has the "protected" class or ID.
- If the ID was found, do not execute `setContent()`; otherwise execute it.

Comment: +1 Great outline. You are right, the `selection.getNode()` returns the context DOM element.